# Search pattern in serial stream

Tags: pattern-matching, signal-processing

I have to search for a pattern in a serial stream of data. This pattern is fixed at the begining of every frame. The search should be done in real time. Is there any reference to study search algorithms and implementations in C?

Thanks

Javier

Answer (score 0):

Checkout using regular expressions for your pattern matching. A couple of libraries to assist with RegEx in C are [Boost.RegEx](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) and [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/xpressive.html)